# Retrieve certificate expiry date using openssl command where there is redirection involved

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

The following linux command works fine where there is no redirection to an authentication website such as *Keycloak* in our case.

```
expiry_date=$(timeout 5s openssl s_client -servername "$domain" -connect "$domain":443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate 2>/dev/null | awk -F '=' '{print $2}' 2>/dev/null)
```

However, with authentication, this times out after the specified interval of 5 seconds. I've not been able to work out how to retrieve certificate details of a site that requires authentication.

Please could I request help with this?

Comment: Use the CLI `curl` with the `-v` option. The `Location` header will contain the redirect URL. Some sites will redirect several times. Use the final `Location` URL to fetch the certificate.